# Laravel HTTP Client Post Response Save File

Tags: php, laravel, http

Sends post request to another api inside Laravel controller.
It returns .pdf file as a response. I wanna save this file to storage. I get FileNotFound exception.

Here is the code

```
public function cvToPDF(Request $request)
{
        $response = Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'])
            ->withToken(Request()->bearerToken())
            ->post('http://some-endpoint', $request->all());
        
        Storage::disk('s3')->putFile('drive/files', $response);

        return $response;
}
```

return $response works in client side. I can download the pdf with this endpoint. But Storage::disk raises exception.

Comment: `PutFile` accepts either a `Illuminate\Http\File` or `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` instance as second argument , make sure it is, instead of download you should store in disk then provide the path in the second argument

Comment: which exception it raises?

Comment: @Pradeep I know. And im trying to convert this response to Illuminate\Http\File instance. Can you help me with this? I ve tried $file = new File($response); But didnt work.

Comment: Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::hashName()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you try to save response, not file.

Workaround at sink() method - this MAY work.

```
public function cvToPDF(Request $request)
{
    $tempName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'response').'.pdf';
    $response = Http::sink($tempName)
        ->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'])
        ->withToken(Request()->bearerToken())
        ->post('http://some-endpoint', $request->all());
    Storage::disk('s3')->putFile('drive/files', new File($tempName));
    return $response;
}
```